# El texto sale fuera de la etiqueta en html-css

Tags: html5, css3

Necesito introducir texto en un `<div>` que es el cuadro de bordes blancos y este se encuentra dentro de un `<span>`.

[image: esta es la pag].

Pero cuando lo hago, el texto se va al fondo de la pagina, ya intenté usar varias propiedades de alinear texto, float, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo css-html**

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Asap Condensed', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:white;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

body{
 background: url("../img/5.jpg") no-repeat ;
 background-size: 100%;
     background-attachment: fixed;

}

h1{
 
 float: left;
 font-size: 55px;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 width: 1288.63px;
 height: 63px;
 margin: 20px 25px 60px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 63px;
 
}

.fila{
 position:relative;
 margin:auto;
 width:100%;
 height: auto;
 clear:both;
 display:table;
}

#anuncios{

 width: 1343px;
 height: 93px;
 text-align: center;
}

#aguile{
 width:1343px;
 height: 93px;
 text-align: center; 
}
h2{
 font-size: 3vw;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p{
 letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 1em 10px 2em;

}

#examples{
   height: 173px;
   margin-top: 2em;
}

#reloj{
   float:left;
   width: 800px;  
   height: 172.41px;  
   margin-left: 265px;  
}

#reloj .casillas{
 margin-right: 8px;
 line-height: 172.41;
 float:left;
 width: 192px;  
    height: 172.41px; 
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 2vw;
    border-radius: 4px; 
}

.casillas div{
 width: 133.63px;
 height: 114.03px;
 
} 


span{
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #55d45a;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 133.63px;
 height: 114.03px;
    
     
}

[class*="col-"]{
 float:left;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:0px;
}



/*=============================================
PANTALLA DE ESCRITORIO GRANDE - LARGE (lg) - revisamos en portatil o pc
=============================================*/

@media(min-width:1200px){

 .col-lg-12{width:100%;}
 .col-lg-11{width:91.66666667%;}
 .col-lg-10{width:83.33333333%;}
 .col-lg-9{width:75%;}
 .col-lg-8{width:66.66666667%;}
 .col-lg-7{width:58.33333333%;}
 .col-lg-6{width:50%;}
 .col-lg-5{width:41.66666667%;}
 .col-lg-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
 .col-lg-3{width: 25%;}
 .col-lg-2 {width: 16.66666667%;}
 .col-lg-1 {width: 8.33333333%;}

}

/*=============================================
PANTALLA DE ESCRITORIO MEDIANO - MEDIUM (md) - revisamos en tablet horizontal 1024px
=============================================*/

@media(max-width:1199px) and (min-width:992px){

 .col-md-12{width:100%;}
 .col-md-11{width:91.66666667%;}
 .col-md-10{width:83.33333333%;}
 .col-md-9{width:75%;}
 .col-md-8{width:66.66666667%;}
 .col-md-7{width:58.33333333%;}
 .col-md-6{width:50%;}
 .col-md-5{width:41.66666667%;}
 .col-md-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
 .col-md-3{width: 25%;}
 .col-md-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
 .col-md-1{width: 8.33333333%;}

}

/*=============================================
PANTALLA DE TABLET - SMALL (sm) - revisamos en tablet vertical 768px
=============================================*/

@media(max-width:991px) and (min-width:768px){

 .col-sm-12{width:100%;}
 .col-sm-11{width:91.66666667%;}
 .col-sm-10{width:83.33333333%;}
 .col-sm-9{width:75%;}
 .col-sm-8{width:66.66666667%;}
 .col-sm-7{width:58.33333333%;}
 .col-sm-6{width:50%;}
 .col-sm-5{width:41.66666667%;}
 .col-sm-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
 .col-sm-3{width: 25%;}
 .col-sm-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
 .col-sm-1{width: 8.33333333%;}

}

/*=============================================
PANTALLA DE PHONES - EXTRA SMALL (xs) - revisamos en movil horizontal 480px o vertical 320px
=============================================*/

@media(max-width:767px){

 .col-xs-12{width:100%;}
 .col-xs-11{width:91.66666667%;}
 .col-xs-10{width:83.33333333%;}
 .col-xs-9{width:75%;}
 .col-xs-8{width:66.66666667%;}
 .col-xs-7{width:58.33333333%;}
 .col-xs-6{width:50%;}
 .col-xs-5{width:41.66666667%;}
 .col-xs-4{width: 33.33333333%;}
 .col-xs-3{width: 25%;}
 .col-xs-2{width: 16.66666667%;}
 .col-xs-1{width: 8.33333333%;}

}





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap+Condensed"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div id="container" class="fila">
   <div id="header" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1  >Coming Soon Page</h1>
   </div> 
   <div id="anuncios" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <a id="aw0" target="_top" href="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=CCvRv4jpqW_3iNZTChwev5pMwmaurtE2T8JbdlQTAjbcBEAEg_NTMJWDf7veNqCWgAYX-keADyAECqAMByAPJBKoE8wFP0K352Soit8M_HTXeO9u8AqtyL4OQakXQrFobh70vG92Jp87ZZaMzzOaqucPx11KyeYzi3AOZLipdpD7o4Ms_qXWiGimXj_IQ_xDwrmcq9vagOUrLTrmFNKtuRQ0qXEoYbv3SllRZirLQFuLbZou8NPEyuW_bqbB3xMXmqvH26fkkF_OGE0wpRRKInrr_T1TrYj2_A3mUREWHbm98oobMl8qRO1_3hYboBHHQpStFp95n7ckN7TP1f_FgsDZPLhlnbeJRGyahnFypnkLOe5MUYbpvsmsEQexw09YOtn4i5EszM3LD4RXNsDE7DNEdYmQA6higBgKAB6PqwyKoB47OG6gH1ckbqAfZyxuoB8_MG6gHpr4bqAeYzhuoB5oG2AcB0ggHCIBhEAEYAfIIG2FkeC1zdWJzeW4tMjUzMTQ4MTgwMDA3MjM5MLEJ7vf4jPCIJFSACgPYEww&amp;num=1&amp;cid=CAASEuRo5jECGZFO1quSTdjRPmw7hA&amp;sig=AOD64_3Fq8N6HpInfn7TJZKZ-C6-DR8FQQ&amp;client=ca-pub-7733626117287363&amp;adurl=http://www.wix.com/startyoursite/hiker-en%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_campaign%3Dbi_ads_en_sca_4%5Etemplates_img%26experiment_id%3Dp.w3layouts.com%5E158491284446%5E%5Efree%2520html%2520templates" data-original-click-url="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&amp;ai=CCvRv4jpqW_3iNZTChwev5pMwmaurtE2T8JbdlQTAjbcBEAEg_NTMJWDf7veNqCWgAYX-keADyAECqAMByAPJBKoE8wFP0K352Soit8M_HTXeO9u8AqtyL4OQakXQrFobh70vG92Jp87ZZaMzzOaqucPx11KyeYzi3AOZLipdpD7o4Ms_qXWiGimXj_IQ_xDwrmcq9vagOUrLTrmFNKtuRQ0qXEoYbv3SllRZirLQFuLbZou8NPEyuW_bqbB3xMXmqvH26fkkF_OGE0wpRRKInrr_T1TrYj2_A3mUREWHbm98oobMl8qRO1_3hYboBHHQpStFp95n7ckN7TP1f_FgsDZPLhlnbeJRGyahnFypnkLOe5MUYbpvsmsEQexw09YOtn4i5EszM3LD4RXNsDE7DNEdYmQA6higBgKAB6PqwyKoB47OG6gH1ckbqAfZyxuoB8_MG6gHpr4bqAeYzhuoB5oG2AcB0ggHCIBhEAEYAfIIG2FkeC1zdWJzeW4tMjUzMTQ4MTgwMDA3MjM5MLEJ7vf4jPCIJFSACgPYEww&amp;num=1&amp;cid=CAASEuRo5jECGZFO1quSTdjRPmw7hA&amp;sig=AOD64_3Fq8N6HpInfn7TJZKZ-C6-DR8FQQ&amp;client=ca-pub-7733626117287363&amp;adurl=http://www.wix.com/startyoursite/hiker-en%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_campaign%3Dbi_ads_en_sca_4%5Etemplates_img%26experiment_id%3Dp.w3layouts.com%5E158491284446%5E%5Efree%2520html%2520templates"><img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/3479336216566961221?sqp=4sqPyQQlQiMqIQhaEAEdAAC0QiABKAEwCTgDQPCTCUgAUAFYAWBacAJ4AQ&amp;rs=AOga4qn-JqaZOzNcSySe9nM4QUNEbQS7DA" border="0" width="728" alt="" class="img_ad"></a>
    
   </div>
   <div id="main-content">
    <div id="aguile" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <h2>We are on the way</h2>
     <p>Stay tuned for something amazing</p>
    </div>
    <div id="examples"  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   
     <div id="reloj">
      <div class="casillas">
       <div>  
        <span>x</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="casillas">
       <div>
        <span></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="casillas">
       <div>
        <span></span>
       </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="casillas">
       <div>
        <span></span>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>

   </div>
  <script type="js/main.js"></script> 
  </div> 
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocasiona ese comportamiento es que dentro de `#reloj .casillas` tienes declarado esta línea:  `line-height: 172.41;` quítalo o cambia el valor a un numero mas pequeño y veras como tu texto se acomoda dentro de tus divs.

Mira [Este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) para ver mas a fondo acerca de esta propiedad.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro.